# Check if an item is in the bag using json (economy system bot discord.py)

Tags: json, python-3.x, discord.py

This is the code for my "bag" or inventory command

```py
@client.command()
async def bag(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()
    
    try:
        bag = users[str(user.id)]["bag"]
    except:
        bag = []


    em = discord.Embed(title = "Bag")
    for item in bag:
        name = item["item"]
        amount = item["amount"]

        em.add_field(name = name, value = amount)    

    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

So i want to check if there is a specific item in the bag. Suppose the item name is "common", how would i do that? Ive tried numerous `for item in bag`  and stuff like that but none work!

Comment: You can use the if/else statements for that.  If users[user.id]["bag"]["common"] > 1: #Do Something

Comment: You could add a field to the item in the json file named `rarity` and then it could contain the rarity of each item.